# botbuilder not waiting for response from HTTP response ( using restsharp)

Tags: c#, azure, async-await, botframework, restsharp

So, 
Apparently everything is working fine in my bot, except It is not waiting for the rest response from restsharp, and directly displaying an empty field instead, and then "Done" without any sort of delay before displaying the empty field. the response takes around 15 seconds to generate, but the bot doesnt even wait 2 seconds.  There are no errors, and the api is working fine.

Here is the code:

```
private async Task OnQuerySelected(IDialogContext context, IAwaitable<string> result){
        try
            {

                string optionSelected = await result;
                string[] tokens = optionSelected.Split(',');

                 var rclient = new RestClient("https://demoappservice.azurewebsites.net/");
                var request = new RestRequest("demoAPI", Method.POST);
                request.AddParameter(
                    "application/json",
                    "{ \"name\": \""+tokens[0]+"\", \"address\": \""+tokens[1]+"\"}", // <- your JSON string
                    ParameterType.RequestBody);
                //request.AddParameter("identifier",this.id);
                //request.AddParameter(this.question.keyword, optionSelected);
                //IRestResponse rresponse = await rclient.Execute(request);
                Task<IRestResponse> t= rclient.ExecuteTaskAsync(request);
                t.Wait();
                 var restResponse = await t;
                //await context.PostAsync("request: "+tokens[0]+tokens[1]);
                string content = restResponse.Content; 
                 await context.PostAsync(content);
 await context.PostAsync("Done!");
            }

            catch (TooManyAttemptsException ex)
            {
                await context.PostAsync($"Ooops! Too many attempts :(. But don't worry, I'm handling that exception and you can try again!");

               context.Wait(this.MessageReceivedAsync);
            }
             catch (Exception exg)
             {
                  await context.PostAsync(exg.ToString());
                  context.Wait(this.MessageReceivedAsync);
            }


     }
```

P.S:. I have also tried the blocking non ASync version of the RESTSharp response, ( as can be seen by the comments), nothing worked.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not very much clear about the question, but from all that i understand you may try making a seperate asynchronous method for the api call like this

```
private async static Task<IRestResponse> NewMethod(string[] tokens)
        {
            var rclient = new RestClient("https://demoappservice.azurewebsites.net/");
            var request = new RestRequest("demoAPI", Method.POST);
            request.AddParameter(
                "application/json",
                "{ \"name\": \"" + tokens[0] + "\", \"address\": \"" + tokens[1] + "\"}", // <- your JSON string
                ParameterType.RequestBody);
            //request.AddParameter("identifier",this.id);
            //request.AddParameter(this.question.keyword, optionSelected);
            //IRestResponse rresponse = await rclient.Execute(request);
            return await rclient.ExecuteTaskAsync(request);
        }
```